# Magento email log is showing me the email was send- but it wasn't

Tags: email, cron

I set up my cronjob in cPanel with following command:

```
wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.xxxxxx.com/cron.php > /dev/null
```

The cronjob is running all 5 minutes. I checked the schedule in the backend and I get the message "scheduler is working". I checked the email Log and it's show that emails were sent! But however, in the end I'm getting no emails. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: are you getting sales emails like order, invoice...etc.

Comment: Yes I after I changed the command I'm getting "could not open input file"

Comment: I'm using this command now php -f /home/user/public_html/xxx.com/cron.php

Comment: check that there is mail server installed in server or not. if not install smtp extension for sending mails.